# Method Illuminate\\View\\View::__toString() must not throw an exception in unix

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am using laravel 4.2

```
die(View::make('amendments.changesPopUp', $this->data));
```

This is the code that I am using to get the view for an `ajax` call. This is working for my local machine running on windows but this is not working for server( unix ). Any idea as to why this is hapening?

and yes the I have checked the lowercase and upper case, the cases for the filename matches. and the weird thing is the error points to the line 0 of the `controller` that it is using.

This is the error that I get

```
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Method Illuminate\\View\\View::__toString() must not throw an exception","file":"mysite.com/app/controllers/myController.php","line":0}}
```

Update: This worked when I used simple php file instead of a blade template. I still do not know what caused the error?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange because it is an ajax call and we have to print any repsonse in order to send over and die is to make sure I do no return anything after I echo the html, but that is not the question.

Comment: Yes it is - probably reason you are getting the error is because you `die()` - which is being treated as throwing the exception.

Comment: please see my update.. it works when i do not use blade template. and this is not the first time I used die.. it is working in my local machine.. please read the question carefully before commenting..

Comment: post your view file please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Error: Method Illuminate\View\View::\_\_toString() must not throw an exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26534016/laravel-error-method-illuminate-view-view-tostring-must-not-throw-an-excep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never `die()` out an input. Laravel expects to handle the response, and you are short circuiting the framework by using `die()`.

Your response should simply be

```
return View::make('amendments.changesPopUp', $this->data);
```

That will then only print the `changesPopUp` file - which will be correctly interrepted by the browser for the AJAX call.

Comment: is there a reason that this would work on windows and not in unix? because this is perfectly working on my local machine, the issue is just in live server. Is there a reason that the laravel interpretation would differ basing on the os used. I understand the unicode may cause the error but I do not see that os interpreting the whole exception in differnt ways.

Comment: I'm not sure - its hard to test. But two tips: 1. You should use Laravel Homestead, so that your 'development' environment is similar to the production environment, otherwise you run into issues like this from time to time. 2. You should never use die() in production on Laravel.

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned already, don't use die() for other than debugging purposes.

Another thing to note is that because PHP's error handling for `__toString` implementations is really bad (no stack traces etc), use `echo View::make(...)->render()` instead of just `echo View::make(...)` to get more descriptive errors - though in your case you can replace echo with die.

But again, don't use die.

Comment: Good tip for using the render() method. I ran into this error and switching to render() rather than __toString() I was able to locate the issue almost immediately.