# Laravel Error: Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception

Tags: php, laravel, runtime-error, tostring, render-to-string

Have you seen this lovely error while working in Laravel?

```
Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception
```

I have seen it and it's incredibly annoying. I have found out two reasons why this error gets thrown. I just want to help people not take hours and hours of time.

View answers & situations below. :)

Comment: Was this ever a question?

Comment: @Raphael_ No sorry! I just wanted to help people if they are running into the same problem that I did and were about to pull their hair out. :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was looking for information about this and eventually Google got me here ;)

Comment: @MaximeBernard Glad it helped someone out! Were you able to get it?

Comment: one up! this saved me some time and gave me some guidance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Situation 1: 
Trying to print out a value in an array.

Answer 1: 
Try printing out the array. Are you sure it's an array? I've gotten this error when it was an object instead of an array. Try doing a print_r and seeing what you get.

Situation 2:
You have this associated array like this:

```
Array
    (
        [post_id] => 65
        [post_text] => Multiple Images!
        [created_at] => 2014-10-23 09:16:46
        [updated_on] => 
        [post_category] => stdClass Object
            (
                [category_label] => Help Wanted
                [category_code] => help_wanted
            )

        [employee_full_name] => Sam Jones
        [employee_pic] => /images/employee-image-placeholder.png
        [employee_email] => jon@gmail.com
        [post_images] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [image_path] => 9452photo_2.JPG
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [image_path] => 8031photo_3.JPG
                    )

            )

    )
```

When you try to access post_images array directly within a View, it throws an error. **No. Matter. What. You. Do.**

Answer 2: 
Check in all the places where you are calling the View. What happened here is that I was trying to access the same view somewhere else in an area where I wasn't giving the post_images array. Took FOREVER to figure out.

I hope this helps someone else. :) I just know the error I kept getting didn't help me anywhere.

Comment: What is this array you're talking about?

Comment: @MaximeBernard, this was just an example. I've gotten this error many times sense I posted this. Every time, it was because I tried to call a value in a View, but didn't set it in the Controller each time I called the view. Such an annoying error!

Comment: Great!! Glad to hear that! :)

Comment: I'm getting kinda the second situation, I can access the item with no hasMany relations, but not the items with a hasMany relation, like I can't echo them out even, if I don't try to it works, I ctrl F searched my whole project but im only trying to make that view in only one place. It gives the error if I try echo those elements.

Comment: @JahanzebKhan, are you trying to echo or print_r? Both are very different.

Comment: echo, I see that you're not supposed to echo an array, but one other problem I'm still running into is if I want a view within a view, then trying to echo that view causes that error, how do you output a view within a view, I tried seaching but couldn't find how.

Comment: @JahanzebKhan, I've seen a view within a view done a couple different ways. Here's one of the ways: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227969/laravel-4-including-a-partial-view-within-a-view-without-using-blade-templa

Remember to submit the data that is require for the sub view. Data from the parent view does NOT go into the child view.

Comment: Thank you so much! I know it's probably simple to search up but I just couldn't find it anywhere!

Comment: @JahanzebKhan you are welcome! Sometimes it's hard to find the right info if you can't find the correct words. Or at least that's what I've experienced.

Answer (score 81):

There is a very simple solution: don't cast View object to a string.

Don't: `echo View::make('..');` or `echo view('..');`

Do: `echo View::make('..')->render();` or `echo view('..')->render();`

**For PHP version <7.4** By casting view, it uses `__toString()` method automatically, which cannot throw an exception. If you call `render()` manually, exceptions are handled normally. This is the case if there is an error in the view - laravel throws an exception.

**It's fixed in PHP >=7.4** you should not encounter this issue: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/tostring_exceptions.

**For PHP version <7.4:** This actually is a PHP limitation, not Laravels. Read more about this "feature" here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53648

Comment: Ahhh. Good tip! :) The laravel documentation never covered that.

Comment: this is very helpful!

Comment: I still got the same error. I am currently using echo view('..'); but when using echo view('..')->render(); nothing happened.

Comment: @KennyUIowa maybe you are rendering a view within a view. All sub-views need to be called with render() manually.

Comment: It works now. However, there are variables (that were in my partial view) that were once recognized when doing a regular @include are now not recognized. I am doing your echo view method within a custom directive.

Comment: While it may be a php limitation, it is a laravel design. They ought to have been more explicit in mentioning the ->render() part. This has bugged me for years. Finally found the solution here today, thank you!

Comment: Can I marry you?

Comment: @FranciscoOchoa sorry mate, already married, but otherwise, why not.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered error like this when an object in my case `$expression = new Expression();` is the same as the parameter variable `submitExpression($intent, $bot_id, **$expression**){` check below code for more details.

```
private function submitExpression($b_id, $expression){
   $expression = new Expression();
   $expression->b_id = $b_id;
   $expression->expression = $expression;
   $expression->save();

}
```

so I changed the above code to something like

```
private function submitExpression($b_id, $statement){      
   $expression = new Expression();
   $expression->b_id = $b_id;
   $expression->expression = $statement;
   $expression->save(); 
}
```

and everything was working fine, hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was finding out where exactly `View::__toString()` was being called in my code, so that I could fix it with using `render()` (as the other answers suggest).

To find it, temporarily edit `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php`, adding logging of the current stack trace:

```
public function __toString()
{
    // Next line added temporarily to debug.
    logger("This causes the '__toString() must not throw an exception' problem: " 
        . (new \Exception())->getTraceAsString());
    return $this->render();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

a similar error is:

FatalErrorException in FooController.php line 0: Method App\Models\Foo::__toString() must not throw an exception

and it was just a bad assignment: `$foo.= new Foo;`

instead of: `$foo = new Foo;`

Comment: Very true! Good call!

Comment: This is not really the explanation. What happens here is that you were concatenating a class with a variable which triggers the `__toString()` method call on the Foo instance. If the `__toString()` call causes an exception somewhere inside, you will see this message.