# Integrating HTML2PDF in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, html2pdf

I am trying to integrate html2pdf library in laravel 5.1. But it is showing error like as follows `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\HTML2PDF' not found`
and my controller code is as follows

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/libs/html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php');
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','en',true,'UTF-8',array(0, 0, 0, 0));
$html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$html2pdf->WriteHTML($html22);
```

my folder path is `app/Http/Controllers/libs/html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php`

i had given the correct path but still it is showing error like `HTML2PDF` not found. Please anyone let me know how to integrate `html2pdf` ? or should i do any changes in `compose.json` file ?

and even i included the line `App\Http\Controllers\HTML2PDF` at the top of the Controller page but no use.

please help me out .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded the latest and it would seem there is no namespace.

Remove the `use App\Http\Controllers\HTML2PDF` and try instantiating html2pdf like `$html2pdf = new \HTML2PDF('P','A4','en',true,'UTF-8',array(0, 0, 0, 0));`

Comment: `FatalErrorException in html2pdf.class.php line 0: Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception` this is error i am getting now ..Can you please help me.

Comment: you must be echoing something?

Comment: That's another issue somewhere else in your code.  You should check this out and if it doesn't answer your question, create a new question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26534016/laravel-error-method-illuminate-view-view-tostring-must-not-throw-an-excep

Comment: @user3158900 i just gone through the link which you shared then i added render() at view . now i m getting this error : `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:`  . for this i added in the view blade php page `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />` . But still it is giving the same error. please help me out

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Package: https://packagist.org/packages/ensepar/html2pdf

add this to your composer.json

```
"ensepar/html2pdf": "4.0.6"
```

and run composer update

after that, you can use it in your controller like so

```
// add this to the beginning of your controller under the namespace declaration
use HTML2PDF;

// after that, you can use the class like so
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','de',false,'UTF-8');
$doc = "<page><h1>Hello World</h1></page>";
$html2pdf->setDefaultFont('Arial');
$html2pdf->writeHTML($doc,false);
$html2pdf->Output(base_path().'/storage/app/helloworld.pdf','F');
```