# laravel Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception

Tags: php, laravel-5

my code is

```
 @foreach($top_15_posts as $status )
       {!!  view('layouts.app-internal.user_status',[
       'status'=>$status,
       'user'=>\App\Eloquent\User::find($status->users_id)
            ]) !!}}
 @endforeach
```

How to overcome this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Error: Method Illuminate\View\View::\_\_toString() must not throw an exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26534016/laravel-error-method-illuminate-view-view-tostring-must-not-throw-an-excep)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check this out.
[Laravel Error: Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26534016/laravel-error-method-illuminate-view-view-tostring-must-not-throw-an-excep)

There is a very simple solution: don't cast View object to a string.

Don't: echo View::make('..'); or echo view('..');

Do: echo View::make('..')->render(); or echo view('..')->render();

By casting view, it uses __toString() method automatically, which cannot throw an exception. If you call render() manually, exceptions are handled normally.

This actually is a PHP limitation, not Laravels. Read more about this "feature" here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53648

-----------AND THIS---------------

Situation 1: Trying to print out a value in an array.

Answer 1: Try printing out the array. Are you sure it's an array? I've gotten this error when it was an object instead of an array. Try doing a print_r and seeing what you get.

Situation 2: You have this associated array like this:

Comment: Actually i used echo and view but phpstorm shows error in missing ; and ) .

Comment: Render () help me to figure out this