# Sleeping Owl Laravel Exception: Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception

Tags: php, laravel-5

I create a model through a service provider

```
AdminColumn::lists('type.name', 'Championship type')
```

In my model ChampionshipTypes i have relationship

```
public function championship(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Championship', 'type_enum_id');
}
```

And in model Championship

```
public function type(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Enum\EnumChampionshipType', 'id');
}
```

When i try load page - Exception Throw

```
FatalErrorException in 74d7252e8b7d20fd1a1f60d84c0c0621d05358d4.php line 0:
Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception
```

Comment: put some view related code as long as your error is related to your view file,

Comment: and have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26534016/laravel-error-method-illuminate-view-view-tostring-must-not-throw-an-excep