# Laravel/Lumen: Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception

Tags: php, laravel, soap, error-handling, lumen

so recently, one of my higher-up coworkers stopped working at my job. Due to this, I'm left with some of his responsibilities. Our server is used by one university over here, so to make requests (i. e. a student pays one of his monthly payments) we use a SOAP service to do stuff (`https://api.uregional.net/zoap/uregional/server`). As you can see, the site displays a "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." message when it's loaded.

Going into the server logs, I get this error a lot of times. **Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception**. I'm not sure what's causing this, since it used to work just fine until some days ago. The full log file can be read here: `https://pastebin.com/EQR5i9sK`

Also, from what I can gather, the code for the SOAP server based on Laravel is this one: `https://github.com/viewflex/zoap`. I don't know much about how it works, so that's why I'm asking. Not sure why that error is popping up now, since as I mentioned, everything used to work just fine some days ago. I've tried to follow some of the stuff from other threads over here, but I feel this is a bit more specific than the situations in other threads.

EDIT: Forgot to add, but the PHP version that the environment is running is 7.2.

Comment: toString is allowed to throw exeptions as of 7.4! Did you update some of the website code and get something a bit newer than your actual PHP version can handle?

Comment: @RiggsFolly not that I know of. I mean, we have two separate environments, we have one for our application (which seems to work fine) and we have one for our SOAP based one, which is this one and we haven't modified a single line of code since 2019. Do you suggest upgrading to PHP 7.4?

Comment: Well Yes because its the way to go, but No, unless you can do some serious testing before deciding to upgrade the live site

Comment: @RiggsFolly what should be tested? We've tried some stuff, I've tried the obvious [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26534016/laravel-error-method-illuminate-view-view-tostring-must-not-throw-an-excep) for the "ZoapController.php" file that the logs are referring to, replacing view(...) with view(...)->return() but I seem to get the same exact result in the log.

Comment: I have NO IDEA as I dont know your site

Comment: @RiggsFolly alright, fair enough. Thanks for your input, I'll keep trying stuff out before upgrading to PHP 7.4.

Comment: Looks like you have a syntax error: `syntax error, unexpected 'version'`